# Excel crashing when I run VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a VBA macro that I run every day where I paste a large set of data and it formats, fills in extra fields using a vlookup against hidden sheets, splits the data into individual sheets, and saves each as a CSV file.

This process runs perfectly 6 out 7 days of the week & only has issues when I run Sunday data.
All VBA macros within the workbook work fine until I get to the step where it saves the CSVs, then it force closes the excel workbook.
I've noticed it saves 1 worksheet (named RCM), but even that it does incorrectly as it only pulls the first row into the file, and the row is from the incorrect sheet.

I thought the issue was with the sheet name (as I have a hidden sheet named RCM1 and the hidden sheets do not get saved). But I've attempted renaming the sheets & am still having the same issue.
I'm now uncertain of what is causing Excel to crash only with this particular data.

Here is the save portion of the macro

```
Sub SaveSheets()
'
' SaveSheets Macro
' Saves sheets as individual CSV files
'

'

Dim csvPath As String
Dim DateName As String
csvPath = "C:\Daily Batch Files"
r = Worksheets("Data").Range("B2")
DateName = "batchredeem.001." & WorksheetFunction.Text(r, "mmmmdd") & "_"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Work").ShowAllData
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible And xWs.Name <> "Magic Buttons" And xWs.Name <> "Data" And xWs.Name <> "Work" Then
            xWs.Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath & "\" & DateName & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        ElseIf xWs.Name = "Work" Then
            xWs.Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT to add additional info:
If I change the name of the sheet before running the macro, it won't save the renamed "RCM" sheet at all- it works for the previous sheet, however, and if I delete the "RCM" sheet, the entire macro runs normally.

***EDIT 2 - I also cannot manually "copy" the "RCM" sheet, but I can manually copy any of the others. Also, if I save the entire workbook, then run the macro, it works normally! I'm stumped & not sure why it isn't working just for this one worksheet.

Comment: It might be helpful to remove the `On Error Resume Next` to determine what line is erroring.

Comment: "then it force closes the excel workbook" -> That seems to be an intended process. The line `ActiveWorkbook.Close False` does exactly what you are describing. It closes the `ActiveWorkbook` and doesn't save changes. So if you had failed to switch the `ActiveWorkbook` to your intended target, it will close whichever other book is currently active. Instead of ambiguously targeting a workbook, I suggest using named variables. This way you can avoid accidentally closing the wrong book.

Comment: @BigBen - thanks for this recommendation! It is saying the error is on the line "xWs.Copy" I got the message "Run-time error '1004': We couldn't copy this sheet." (It is the sheet I mentioned in the original post, sheet named "RCM"). For some reason, it is copying the first non-blank cell from another sheet named "magic buttons"

Comment: @Toddleson - any idea why I'm only having this issue with this one sheet? If I remove the sheet titled "RCM", the whole thing runs without a problem.

Comment: Try copying the sheet manually in Excel - do you get a more meaningful/helpful error message?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I get an error message "Microsoft Excel - We couldn't copy this sheet." All other sheets are fine. If I save the workbook then try to copy or run the macro, it runs normally without an error.

Comment: I've posted an answer 9 days ago yet you haven't responded. Did you test the procedure and could you share what happened when you did?

Answer (score 2):

### Export Worksheets As One-Worksheet Files

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportVisibleWorksheets()
' Saves worksheets as individual CSV files

    ' Source
    Const sExceptionsList As String = "Magic Buttons,Work,Data"
    Const sSpecialName As String = "Work" ' exported differently
    ' Source Lookup
    Const slName As String = "Data" ' included in the exceptions list
    Const slCellAddress As String = "B2"
    ' Destination
    Const dDateLeft As String = "batchredeem.001."
    Const dDateMidFormat As String = "mmmmdd"
    Const dDateRight As String = "_"
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "C:\Daily Batch Files\"
    ' The following two depend on each other!
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".csv"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlCSV
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' doesn't exist
    
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(slName)
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range(slCellAddress)
    
    Dim sExceptions() As String: sExceptions = Split(sExceptionsList, ",")
    Dim dDateMid As String
    dDateMid = WorksheetFunction.Text(sCell.Value, dDateMidFormat) ' English
    'dDateMid = Format(sCell.Value, dDateMidFormat) ' International
    Dim dDateName As String: dDateName = dDateLeft & dDateMid & dDateRight
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim dwsCount As Long
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    Dim DoNotCopy As Boolean
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        
        If sws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            
            If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, sExceptions, 0)) Then
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & dDateName & sws.Name & dFileExtension
            ElseIf StrComp(sws.Name, sSpecialName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sws.Name & dFileExtension
                If sws.AutoFilterMode Then
                    sws.ShowAllData
                End If
            Else
                DoNotCopy = True
            End If
            
            If DoNotCopy Then
                DoNotCopy = False
            Else
                sws.Copy
                Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite: no confirmation
                On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if file is open
                    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=dFileFormat
                    ErrNum = Err.Number
                On Error GoTo 0
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                If ErrNum = 0 Then
                    dwsCount = dwsCount + 1
                Else
                    ErrNum = 0
                End If
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Select Case dwsCount
        Case 0: MsgBox "No worksheets exported.", vbExclamation
        Case 1: MsgBox "One visible worksheet exported.", vbInformation
        Case Else
            MsgBox dwsCount & " visible worksheets exported.", vbInformation
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and is jsut what you say here. Just by adding Option Explicit, you solve the problem. The thing is that sometimes the excel closes when initiating the macro without even giving an error message. But what closes excel is that some variables are not explicitly declared